# Downloading a file cause error when it contains spaces - PHP

Tags: php

Consider that i am uploading a file with following names:

1. test.pdf
2. test file.pdf

When i download the test.pdf it's working fine..

But when i download test file.pdf it doesn't. **The case is the space between the file name.**

**Unfortunately i should not change the file name when i upload (If i can i will set "_" using str_replace between spaces and resolve this issue).**

**Now how should i download the file ?**

My code is given below:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test file.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('test file.pdf');
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http there are usefull comments.

Answer (score 5):

> The case is the space between the file name.

Put it in double quotes to fix the issue. With an example:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test file.pdf"');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('test file.pdf');
```

This should work. I've just tried using readfile on a file with a space, and that seems to cause no issues.

Answer (score 5):

The content-disposition header is not part of HTTP (but popular to use with HTTP requests), see [in RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.5).

The documentation of it is part of [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) which is in the MIME domain. It's specified as `filename-param` of which the filename is actually the `value` part. That `value` is defined in [RFC 2045 Appendix A -- Collected Grammar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#appendix-A)
 as:

```
value := token / quoted-string
token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs,
             or tspecials>
tspecials :=  "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" /
              "," / ";" / ":" / "\" / <">
              "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "="
              ; Must be in quoted-string,
              ; to use within parameter values
```

See as well [RFC 2616, 2.2 Basic Rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2).

It's all `US-ASCII` and I assume the space needs escaping, e.g. multiple words in double-quotes (other chars work as well for that `quoted string`, `token` is a single word):

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test file.pdf"');
```

Keep in mind that other chars need other escaping/encoding, see [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) and [this pear ticket](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=14232).

But in the end you need to test with every browser. I think it's easier if you replace the space with a `_` or `-` inside the filename to be more stable:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test-file.pdf');
```

Hope this is helpful to understand your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [URL encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) the filename:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test%20file.pdf');
```

Comment: Some browsers *might* offer it with `%20` in the filename (as-is).

Comment: By encoding it, I collected some grammar in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786964/downloading-a-file-cause-error-when-it-contains-spaces-php/6787253#6787253

Answer (score 2):

If using the 'header' function for the downloading of files, especially if you're passing the filename as a variable, remember to surround the filename with double quotes, otherwise you'll have problems in Firefox as soon as there's a space in the filename.

So instead of typing:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filename));
?>
```

you should type:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
?>
```

If you don't do this then when the user clicks on the link for a file named "Example file with spaces.txt", then Firefox's Save As dialog box will give it the name "Example", and it will have no extension.